# Can I read application properties in a Micronauts @Singleton class with @EventListener?

Tags: java, kotlin, properties, micronaut

I have a `@Singleton` class with a method annotated with `@EventListener` in my Micronaut project:

```
@Singleton
class Bot {

    @Inject
    private val environment: Environment? = null

    @EventListener
    fun initialize(event: ServerStartupEvent) {

        val key = environment?.getProperty("discord.api.key", String::class.java)?.get().orEmpty()
        
        // code that is using the key variable

    }
}
```

The key is in `application.yml` file:

```
discord:
  api:
    key: MY_API_KEY // key is here as it is, without " or ' quotes, tried to enclose it with quotes - it doesn't work either
```

But when I'm trying to run the application, I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token, make sure you're using the token from the developer portal Bot section and not the application client secret or public key.
        at discord4j.common.util.TokenUtil.getSelfId(TokenUtil.java:35)
        at discord4j.rest.RestResources.<init>(RestResources.java:58)
        at discord4j.core.CoreResources.<init>(CoreResources.java:44)
        at discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder.lambda$create$0(DiscordClientBuilder.java:45)
        at discord4j.rest.RestClientBuilder.build(RestClientBuilder.java:249)
        at discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder.build(DiscordClientBuilder.java:85)
        at discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder.build(DiscordClientBuilder.java:73)
        at com.codenamite.majorbot.MajorBot.initialize(MajorBot.kt:23)
        at com.codenamite.majorbot.$MajorBotDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:151)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:3414)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.AdapterIntroduction.intercept(AdapterIntroduction.java:81)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:96)
        at com.codenamite.majorbot.MajorBot$ApplicationEventListener$initialize1$Intercepted.onApplicationEvent(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.notifyEventListeners(DefaultBeanContext.java:1326)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.publishEvent(DefaultBeanContext.java:1311)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.fireStartupEvents(NettyHttpServer.java:512)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.start(NettyHttpServer.java:355)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.start(NettyHttpServer.java:114)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.lambda$start$2(Micronaut.java:77)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:75)
        at com.codenamite.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:702)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
        at discord4j.common.util.TokenUtil.getSelfId(TokenUtil.java:32)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

The `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` part is telling me that the key was null, so the `.orEmpty()` part was used.

I have no clue what is happening, the only one idea that comes to my mind is that the properties are not available at the moment when this code is running, but I have no idea how to fix this... Or maybe there is something else? I am running out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend using either configuration injection: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#valueAnnotation

```
@Context
class Bot(@Value("${discord.api.key}") String key) {

   init {
     // code that is using the key variable
   }
}
```

or what I prefer configuration properties
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#configurationProperties

your bot will look like that:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("discord")
class DiscordConfig {

    @NotBlank
    var token: String = ""

}



@Context
class Bot(config: DiscordConfig) {

   init {
     val client = DiscordClient.create(config.token)
     // code that is using the key variable
   }
}
```

I see no need of using the server start event.
If you annotate your "singleton" with "context" the bean is instanciated on startup which is quite the same like a server start event.
Using constructor injection makes shure the stuff is there on instanciation.

Oli

Comment: "maybe the syntax is not 100% correct, I usually use kotlin therefore my java is getting a little rusty" - It would be helpful if you posted a Kotlin solution.  The code in the question is written in Kotlin and the question is tagged with "kotlin".

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thx for reminding me, i completely overlooked the kotlin annotation :-)

Comment: What is going to initialize the value of the `token` property in `DiscordConfig`?

Comment: its injected as environment variable from the outside

Comment: Thank You @IEE1394, I am gonna check this solution later on today :)

Comment: " If you annotate your "singleton" with "context" the bean is instanciated on startup which is quite the same like a server start event" That is not really correct. The order will be different. I agree with the approaches to read the config, but its unclear why the work should be done in the event handler or a context scope bean

Comment: @dziki Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)